# Single text field used for different keyword (one at a time) for search

Tags: php, mysql

I have to use a single text box to use for search by order id or first name or last name or phone or email address, how can i Identify the input value to be related to required fields, if u have the idea to make it happen plss guide me...

I have this type of query to be executed when keyword found.

```
select orders.* 
from orders 
join customers on customers.customerid=orders.customerid
where customers.firstname = 'John' -- or whatever
```

I am working in PHP and Mysql

Comment: Thanx Haim I was about to correct that

Comment: Just two small notes: you'd better avoid using '*', specify all of the fields; and maybe you want to use 'like' instead of '=' in your WHERE clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can not know. The only way is you write all of the `OR` to check all the related condition

Answer (score 0):

you can add a second input. for example "search in"..